# Is there a way to remove the login flow and intergrate Profile Edit with SAML?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

We are trying to link the starter pack profile edit policy with our application and remove the log in portion of the flow. Any recommendations on how this can be done?

`<UserJourney Id="ProfileEdit"> <OrchestrationSteps> <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections"> <ClaimsProviderSelections> <!--<ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="moAzureADExchange" />--> <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" /> </ClaimsProviderSelections> </OrchestrationStep> <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange"> <ClaimsExchanges> <!--<ClaimsExchange Id="moAzureADExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AzureAD-B2C" />--> <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" /> </ClaimsExchanges> </OrchestrationStep> <!--<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange"> <Preconditions> <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true"> <Value>authenticationSource</Value> <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value> <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action> </Precondition> </Preconditions> <ClaimsExchanges> <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserRead" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" /> </ClaimsExchanges> </OrchestrationStep>--> <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange"> <Preconditions> <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true"> <Value>authenticationSource</Value> <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value> <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action> </Precondition> </Preconditions> <ClaimsExchanges> <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" /> </ClaimsExchanges> </OrchestrationStep> <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange"> <ClaimsExchanges> <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserProfileUpdateExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" /> </ClaimsExchanges> </OrchestrationStep> <!--<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="Saml2AssertionIssuer" />--> <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" /> </OrchestrationSteps> <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" /> </UserJourney>`

Answer (score 0):

You have SAML in the question? What is the use case?

If you remove the login on ProfileEdit, there is **a security issue**.

But you can do it by having a self-asserted screen that collects, e.g. an email address and then doing a "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" and then doing "SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate".

Comment: What about passing the profile edit updated attributes over to the application. Currently when the user clicks continue on the profile edit page, they are redirected to the sign up page where after sign up they receive a 500 error.

Comment: You would get the claims returned via "SendClaims". Your flow doesn't sound right. You should first log in, then edit, and then get the claims back. Did you change something?

Comment: Made an edit on the OP - with the user journey of the profile edit

Comment: What does your "SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" look like?